# Vue3 datatable not updating after Axios request

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

Im building a datatable and it shows my test-data correctly.
However, after i do my Axios request, it doesnt update the state.tableData variable!
What am I doing wrong here?

I keep seeing a table with the value 'test1', and not 'test2' and 'test3'?
I am using Vue3 with the composition API.

This is the template part:

```html
<template>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body pt-0">
      <Datatable
        :table-data="state.tableData"
        :table-header="state.tableHeader"
      >
        <template v-slot:cell-name="{ row: item }">
          {{ item.name }}
        </template>
      </Datatable>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

And the JS code:

```html
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, toRefs, reactive, ref, onMounted } from "vue";
import Datatable from "@/components/kt-datatable/KTDatatable.vue";
import axios, { AxiosRequestConfig, AxiosResponse} from 'axios';

export default defineComponent({
    name: "listing",
    components: {
        Datatable,
    },
    setup() {

        interface fieldDefinitions {
            name: string;
        }

        const state = reactive({
            tableData: ref<fieldDefinitions[]>([]),
            tableHeader: [{
                name: "Naam",
                key: "name",
                sortable: true,
            }]
        });


        function getListings() {
            const config: AxiosRequestConfig = {
                method: 'get',
                url: 'https://myurl',
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            };

            axios(config)
            .then(function (response) {
                //state.tableData = response.data.data;
                state.tableData = [{'name':'test2'},{'name':'test3'}];
                console.log(state.tableData);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        }

        onMounted(async () => {
            getListings()
        });

        return { state,getListings };

    },
});
</script>
```

Comment: Not quite sure but try: `state.tableData.value = [{'name':'test2'},{'name':'test3'}]`. I see that you define your tableData as `ref<someType>`.
If this works, try removing the ref definition and proceed with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you have `tableData: ref<fieldDefinitions[]>([]),` you are assigning `state.tableData = [{'name':'test2'},{'name':'test3'}];` not `state.tableData = ref([{'name':'test2'},{'name':'test3'}])`. But even then, state.tableData.value is not needed since reactive unwraps refs. see [docs](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#reactive). So as far as I can tell and reproduce, your code should be working properly to trigger reactivity.

The issue is likely due to your `Datatable` component is not updating properly.

Comment: The component wasnt working correctly indeed... thanks for pointing this out. Switched to normal tables.